# Cookie's key stored in memory, can't switch server

Tags: cookies, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, session-cookies

I've an Asp.Net Core RC2 application and I'm having issues with cookie's authentication. In startup.cs file I've a base configuration:

```
app.UseIdentity();
app.UseCookieAuthentication();
```

I'm not using EntityFramework, because I'm using a documental database, for which I implemented Identity's interfaces IUserStore and IRoleStore.

When I login into localhost for debug, even if I set persistent cookies, they remain valid until I shutdown the application. When I restart it cookies are expired, and server redirects me to login page. This says me that cookie's keys are kept in memory. Why it doesn't keep keys on user's profile records on db? Cookies works until the application is kept alive.

This is an issue when I deploy the application on production server. I'm using a production/staging solution, and I noted that when I deploy the application on staging and I switch servers, all logged in user's sessions expire. This is a big issue. I also can't share cookies key on a local directory, as suggested by https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/data-protection/compatibility/cookie-sharing.html, because two servers are different. How can I solve?

Comment: Are you worried that people would get logged off when you migrate to a new machine? Why?

Comment: Because with an agile development I could also switch machine like every day

Comment: Any reason why you **can't** use distributed memory cache, like redis? The redis support comes out of the box with ASP.NET Core, you just need an redis cluster and add the package to your application and call the `AddRedisCache()` method Startup class, somewhere before your authorization middleware is registered? This makes your apps store their values in Redis rather than the default InMemoryCache

Comment: I've never used Redis. I will look into it. Exists any other solution that doesn't imply a new external tool setup?

Comment: Check out the ASP.NET Core Caching repository for the built in caching providers. https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/tree/dev/src. There's also a SqlServer Caching option. Have a look at the samples folder https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/tree/dev/samples. Redis is just the most natural choice for distributed systems and it's an distributed in memory database

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you need to use the same data protection keys across multiple machines, whereas the [documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/data-protection/configuration/overview.html) says that the default settings are good for a single machine

So the solution is to take control over the location where the keys are stored so you can deploy the keys to each server along with your app. I also needed to do this in my app because I'm using dataprotection to encrypt some stuff in the db, such as social auth secrets, and I need to be able to decrypt those if the app is migrated to a different machine.

I did change the key location in my app like this in startup:

```
string pathToCryptoKeys = appBasePath + System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "dp_keys" + System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
services.AddDataProtection()
            .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(pathToCryptoKeys));
```

but it is very very important to keep these keys secure so a great deal of caution should be used in thinking about where to store them and who has access to that location, putting them below the approot like in my example is probably not the best solution